# Creating a filter view in Jspresso containing a date picker without comparison operators

Tags: java, jspresso

In my Jspresso application, I have an entity with `startDate` and `endDate`.
I've created a filter module on this entity with a search on a `validityDate` that the user has to type in. The generated query should return the list of entities for which this `validityDate` is between `startDate` and `endDate`.
So I customized the query and this works well.

Unfortunately, the filter view displays the `validityDate` field preceeded by a search operator (`<`,`>`, `between`…) which is irrelevant in my case; so I simply ignore the operator in the query.

I would like to hide the operator in the view to only have the date with a date picker.

Comment: Welcome to SO:SE. Maybe it would be useful to insert a snapshot (you can add a link), or the relevant part of your code. See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it can easily be achieved using the current Jspresso version (4.0.7 as of now). The problem is that the code responsible for exploding the comparable scalar properties into a (comparator, min, max) filtering structure is too deeply nested for it to be overridden using dependency injection :

The following method :

```java
protected boolean isPropertyFilterComparable(
      IPropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor) {
    return propertyDescriptor instanceof INumberPropertyDescriptor
        || propertyDescriptor instanceof IDatePropertyDescriptor
        || propertyDescriptor instanceof ITimePropertyDescriptor
        || propertyDescriptor instanceof IDurationPropertyDescriptor;
}
```

is located into the `RefQueryComponentDescriptor` class whose instances are constructed at runtime by the `BasicQueryComponentDescriptorFactory` but in a private method (i.e. `createOrGetQueryComponentDescriptor`). So even if you could inject your own customized instance of `BasicQueryComponentDescriptorFactory`, you would have to copy/paste too much code to reach the `isPropertyFilterComparable` method.

Since your use case is perfectly valid, I suggest that you create an enhancement request on the [Jspresso GitHub](https://github.com/jspresso/jspresso-ce/issues).

A little less straightforward but more versatile approach might be to open the various comparable properties (number, date, time and duration) for an extra customization in order to tell Jspresso whether to generate or not the comparator structure when those properties are added in a filter view.

something like :

```groovy
date 'validityDate', filterComparable:true
```

But this would require a change in the SJS DSL.

Comment: The related [GitHub issue](https://github.com/jspresso/jspresso-ce/issues/12) has been created.

Comment: The issue has been implemented in current Jspresso 4.1-SNAPSHOT